# How to setup server send in-app notification? (not a push notification)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send message from server, server will send a message (notification) but that notification will be in-app notification not a push notification - Or can we send push notification in such way that it will not appear in notification bar or not on lock screen, it should only be appear in app.

Example:
Users are playing one test, once a contest finished winner will get in-app notification in which app will show a card with celebration icon

can't use websocket because if app is not running then app will not have websocket connection and will not get notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase in-app notifications for this task. And I think if you need to show a congratulation card then why are you not doing it locally? make a layout and show that in the dialog.

Comment: In firebase in-app notification we can't sent message from server, I don't found any api or sdk related to that. 
why are you not doing it locally? 
-> how app will know that the user xyz is a winner? without sending messaging from server

Comment: You can have a winner node and in-app attach a value event listener and accordingly show the card.

Comment: can you share any example?

Comment: Suppose you create a node that will announce the winner in the firebase real-time database and  when a user gives a test attach a value event Listener to that particular node ... so when you announce the winner then store data to that node so when the value will be changed then the value event Listener will be invoked in-app and you will get new value in app... then you need to update UI accordingly .

Comment: can we sen push notification? which will not appear notification bar or lock screen?

Comment: I think you can do it .... by handling as you want in onMessageReceived()